# Where do I find the 'Internet Time' (NTP) settings in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ntp

In Windows XP you can get to the 'Internet Time' settings (to select an [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) server or force an update) via the 'Date and Time Properties' in Control Panel.

Where is this found in Windows 7?

As pointed out, I won't be able to do this if attached to 
a domain. My problem was that my PC was trying to synchronise with 'time.windows.com' which is blocked by our firewall. In the end I changed the registry key (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers`) to point to our internal NTP server and the time is now synchronising fine.

(I know that domain computers should synchronise with their domain controllers, but this machine is not actually logged in to the domain most of the time.)

Comment: Switch control panel "View By" to small icons, then the Date and Time icon will appear.

Comment: @Moab. I can see the Date & Time properties but not the Internet time tab.

Comment: Please post your answer as an actual answer and remove that portion from your question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. Click on the clock in your system tray

   - This will bring up the calendar and time
2. Click **Change date and time settings...**

   - The Date and Time dialog will appear
3. Click on the **Internet Time** tab
4. Click **Change settings**

   - The Internet Time Settings dialog will appear.

From here you can select which time server to sync your computer's time to as well as if you want to sync it up right then and there.

Comment: FYI:  The Internet Time tab does NOT appear if the computer is part of a windows domain.  (AFAIK, it will automatically sync its time to the domain controller in that case).

Comment: @Dan. That explains why I see the 'Internet time' tab at home and not at work. Will have another look after the weekend.