# Where do I find the "Internet Time" (NTP) settings in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ntp

In Windows 7, you could get to the "Internet Time" settings by following the instructions in [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/161763/83694).

Now, I can get to this interface, but there is no option to set a custom NTP server or even see the current NTP server:

[image: Windows 10 settings >> Time & language >> Date & time]

I want to get to this dialog box:

[image: Windows 7: Internet Time Settings]

**Where are "Internet Time Settings" in Windows 10?**

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### "Internet Time Settings" dialog box

1. Go to **Control Panel**.
2. Search for "*Date and Time*".
3. Click on "*Set the time and date*".
4. Click on the "*Internet Time*" tab.
5. Click on "*Change settings…*".

[image: Windows 10: Internet Time Settings]

### Registry key

You can still modify the default server registry key at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers` to set a custom NTP server.

[image: Registry Editor for setting NTP servers]

Comment: I'm at that traditional "Date and Time" window, but there is not an "Internet Time" tab. This is on Windows 10 Pro, version 1703, running as a user with Admin rights.

Comment: @Johann: See [Internet Time tab has disappeared from the Date and Time applet of the Control Panel](https://superuser.com/q/250547/83694)

Answer (score 8):

For domain users, the domain controller (DC) will also be missing the Internet time, as well as all domain workstations. Once the Domain Controller is set to a manual peer, the workstations can run, from an elevated command prompt:

```
net time \\domaincontroller.domain.tld /set /y
```

to synchronise with the DC.

Example:

```
net time \\dc.domain.local /set /y
```

For virtual servers, the DC/member servers, clients will have issues even with these settings set on the DC. The core server controls it, and it does have the *Internet Time* tab, so you can set the manual peer there and then everything will work as it should, because virtual servers use the physical resources from the core server.

Answer (score 3):

For *Windows 10*, **Creators update** these settings can be found like this:

1. Open *Settings* (Click on *Windows Logo* at lower left corner and then click the *cog wheel*)
2. Select *Time & language*
3. Under *Related settings* select *Additional date, time & regional settings*. A new window with the 'traditional' settings interface should now open.
4. Click on *Set the time and date*. Another popup window opens.
5. Select tab *Internet Time* and make your changes within *Change settings...*
6. *OK*, *OK*, *Close*, *Close*... ;-)

Alternative way:

1. Click the loupe (magnifying glass) at the lower left corner of the screen.
2. Start typing *Control Panel* and select it as soon as it appears within the results. The control panel opens.
3. Type *Time* in the search field at the top right corner.
4. Select *Set the time and date*. Another popup window opens.
5. Select tab *Internet Time* and make your changes within *Change settings...*
6. *OK*, *OK*, *Close*, *Close*... ;-)

Second alternative way:

1. Open *Settings* (Click on *Windows Logo* at lower left corner and then click the *cog wheel*)
2. Search for "*date time*".
3. Click on *Date and Time* (not *Date & time settings* !). A popup window opens.
4. Select tab *Internet Time* and make your changes within *Change settings...*
5. *OK*, *OK*, *Close*, *Close*... ;-)

Comment: Does the accepted solution still work within the Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703)?

Comment: Starting with **Windows 10 Creators Update** the _Control Panel_ can no longer be opened directly (right click on the windows logo).

Comment: Yes, I understand that... but the accepted solution specifically says `1. Go to Control Panel.`  It doesn't say anything about how you need to right-click on the Windows logo.  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members (including yours), but the fact remains that the accepted solution still works within the **Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703)**.

Comment: The accepted solution was valid at the time when it has been written, but since the advent of _Creators Update_ Windows 10 is behaving slightly different. This solutions shows how to find things now (after installing Creators Update).

Comment: To clarify, the accepted solution **is** still valid since there is nothing wrong with the directions within that answer.  Your post is still a valuable contribution and we are grateful for your effort, but essentially it just describes three different ways to open the `Control Panel`.

Comment: You mention the control panel in an answer written again 1703.  This is a mistake because, control panel no longer has a shortcut, on the start menu starting with 1703.  Perhaps its simply the lack of screenshots that makes this question less useful then it could be.

Comment: Since this is still a problem: control panel access has been both deprecated and made more difficult in WIndows 10 (running 10.0.17763.503 here right now, no idea what that one is called), and you start the control panel by using the "Run" command to start "control". Not that it helps, since the only things you can change there now are representations of date and time. The "Additional time, date and regional settings" in the system settings (the "new control panel") are now hidden behind the very wrong description "Add clocks for different time zones".