# Windows 10 time (and date) is wrong on new computers

Tags: windows-10, ntp

I've been manually configuring six Lenovo Yoga 500 laptops running Windows 10 home over the last week and they have consistently not been able to get the right time in the UK. These are out of the box systems, booted up and the initial set-up questions answered.

In each case, there were errors in the log that Windows was unable to reach time.windows.com,0x9 and the date is in the future. I've been "fixing" it by changing the time server to pool.ntp.org and the time instantly corrects.

What's at fault here? I can't believe that time.windows.com has been down for over a week or is it just that unreliable? Or is a fault in Windows 10 that is fixed by changing the NTP server?

Comment: Sounds like a DNS problem on your end

Comment: Related: [Where do I find the “Internet Time” (NTP) settings in Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/q/954477/194694)

Answer (score 3):

Personally I've seen a lot of issues with time.windows.com and almost always switch to time.nist.gov or pool.ntp.org. Never bothered thinking about why that is; I just assumed they were too busy / unreliable.

As far as the time being in the future, it's possible that your system's clock (in BIOS / UEFI settings) is off and it's grabbing the time from there. To confirm this, you can do one of two things. First, you can simply just check the system clock itself. Second, before you sync to pool.ntg.org, you can check the time source from the command line by doing the following as administrator:

```
sc start w32time
w32tm /query /source
```

Comment: Will try this next time I get a laptop to build